# Sql merge multiple rows into column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

Table A

```
A1 | A2
 1 | 2
 2 | 3
 3 | 4
```

Table B

```
B1 | B2
1  | 3
1  | 5
4  | 3
```

A1,A2,B1 and B2 are all ID's

I want to join Table A with Table B only when A.A1 = B.B1.

```
Select A.A1, A.A2, B.B2 from A JOIN B ON A.A1 = B.B1
```

should return

```
A1 | A2 | B2
1  | 2  | 3
1  | 2  | 5
```

But i want obtain data in this format, i would like final result as:

```
A1   | Col2
1    | 2
1    | 3
1    | 5
```

Extra question: How can i know from which column information comes?

```
A1   | Col2 | Table
1    | 2    | A
1    | 3    | B
1    | 5    | B
```

Thx for the help.

Edit1: Union wont work, i dont want to stack simply the fields from both tables, i want join data under a condition, but since A2 and B2 are ID´s of same type i would like to have data in a single collumn, and it would simplify future queries over the result.

Comment: Please clarify WHY you want this, and please go back and **accept some  answers to your past questions.**

Comment: i didnt forgot them, need really to back at them, vote in the one more near and tell my solution

Answer (score 2):

To present multiple tables as a single table, you use `UNION`:

```
SELECT A1 as Col1, A2 as Col2, 'A' as Col3 FROM table_A
UNION ALL
SELECT B1 as Col1, B2 as Col2, 'B' as Col3 FROM table_B
```

---

Based on the revised question, the addition of a `where` condition provides the result you're looking for. I still don't see any reason that you need a join, based on the scenario presented.

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT A1, A2 as Col2, 'A' as "TABLE" FROM table_A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B1, B2 as Col2, 'B' as "TABLE" FROM table_B)
WHERE A1 = 1;
```

Comment: Not what he's after I don't think.

Comment: @JNK: He wants 4 columns from table A and 4 columns from table B to appear as 8 columns in the result set, ideally while knowing which table each row originated in. I don't see anything in the question to lead me to believe that this is not the solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: are you sure you are looking at the right question?  He wants two fields from A and two fields from B merged into a single result set with 2 fields, but normalized from 3 fields.

Comment: @JNK: Look at the data the OP is presenting, not the descriptive text. The OP clearly is unfamiliar with the correct terminology and process, but the result they're looking for is definitely the result of a `union`.

Comment: @Allan - he wants a `UNION` of the `JOIN`ed result set.  This will show all records regardless of whether a relation exists or not.  You are right though that I was reading the description more than the sample!

Comment: @Allan: I agree with your solution, but you should not say *columns* when you are talking about *rows*, that is very confusing.

Comment: @Andriy: You're absolutely right and I would change that comment if I could.

Comment: HI, Union wont work, i dont want to stack simply the fields from both tables, i want join data under a condition, but since A2 and B2 are ID´s of same type i would like to have data in a single collumn, and it would simplify future queries over the result.

Comment: @blueomega: What you want is still not clear. With your revised question, the result is still the same as the `union` solution, just with the results filtered by the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear your question is, but what you want this might be it.

```
CREATE TABLE a(a1 INT, a2 INT);
CREATE TABLE b(b1 INT, b2 INT);

INSERT INTO a VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO a VALUES(3, 4);

INSERT INTO b VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(1, 5);
INSERT INTO b VALUES(4, 3);

COMMIT;

SELECT a1 AS "1", a2 AS "2", 'A' AS "src" FROM a
UNION
SELECT a1, b2, 'B' FROM a, b WHERE a1 = b1;

1                      2                      src 
---------------------- ---------------------- --- 
1                      2                      A   
1                      3                      B   
1                      5                      B   
2                      3                      A   
3                      4                      A
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, possibly:

```
SELECT
  u.*
FROM (
  SELECT A1, B1 AS Col2, 'A' AS SourceTable FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B1, B2 AS Col2, 'B' AS SourceTable FROM B
) u
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A1 FROM A
    INTERSECT
    SELECT B1 FROM B
  ) i ON u.A1 = i.A1
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the two `AS` in `AS u` and `AS i` otherwise it won't run.

Comment: Done. Knowing little about Oracle, I had to look up if it supported `INTERSECT`, but I couldn't imagine that `AS` (with table aliases) would not be supported. Thanks!